# Symfony: How to filter deprecated alerts based on bundles

Tags: symfony, debugging

I've updated to Symfony 2.8. The debug toolbar tells me about a lot of deprecated calls but the majority of them are of third party bundles.

Is there a way to filter out these deprecation notices, so I can see only the ones that comes from my bundle? This way I can fix them, while currently I have to dig into a lot of notices and maybe I will lose some of mine deprecated calls.

Answer (score 1):

There is no option to filter them. And i think it's by purpose - as long as any of used bundles/components will use deprecated calls - you will can't upgrade to new release (3.0 for example).

I think that Bundle name is not even part of logged message (there is just stacktrace).